# Use application data specific to user in services running through Network Service account

Tags: windows, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, appdata

I have a Azure DevOps Pipeline configured to run over Network Service account. It tries to run an application which stores its settings in the user's Roaming AppData folder.

When, I try to run the application through the pipeline, it throws errors telling settings not found.

I believe this is because Network Service account's AppData is being maintained separately.

```
%windir%\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService\AppData\Roaming
```

I was thinking to copy the AppData files from the user's AppData folder to this location. However, I don't think this is the correct way to handle this problem.

What if I copy the AppData to the the ProgramData folder? Would that work?

```
%ProgramData%\
```

Is there a better way to do this?

**Update**

I copied the Application's settings file from the user's appdata to the NetworkService account's roaming folder. It works fine.

```
%windir%\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService\AppData\Roaming
```

I recieve the error if the application's settings file is not found. the pipeline is working perfectly.

Comment: Did you try to use `system.debug=true` variable to re-run your pipeline to check the detailed log? And please share the whole, main error with us.

Comment: @PerryQian-MSFT. I am not sure if running in debug mode will help as the error is coming from the application and not from the pipeline. It is just that the application is unable to find it's settings file in the NetworkService account's appdata. I copied and it worked fine, but I am not sure if that it is a correct way.